# Android: onResume()

Tags: android, android-activity, mobile, onresume

Is there any way to differentiate between the two:-

1. Activity called when app came from background to foreground
2. Activity called from another activity.

does android have any way to differ or we have to implement our own custom logic (like keeping track of last active activity) ?

Comment: use a flag in `onPause()` then check the flag in `onResume()`

Comment: You may use onSavedInstanceState() func and when it goes to backgorund put some data there, but u should now that onSavedInstanceState calling not only when Activity goes to background but also when orientation of screen changing and some other cases. Btw try read through this https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle, if u will got some question u may ask it here. And answering on your question, yes you should implement your custom logic in android methods liek onPause, onSavedInstanceState and etc. depends from use cases

Answer (score 0):

You are getting it wrong. Whenever an activity is created, `onResume` is called just after `onStart`. Whenever your activity goes back stack `onPause` is called. Again if your activity comes back to foreground then `onResume` is called. So, it is not like, `onResume` is called before `onPause`. Whenever activity is returning from `onPause` state, `onResume` gets called instead of `onStart` or `onCreate`. This happens so that Android does not have to create Activity instance again and again though those instances are not properly destroyed. This is quite memory efficient too.

Answer (score 0):

Lifecycle callback `onCreated` will be called only if activity is created from scratch (launched from another activity for example) and `onResume` will be called in both cases if it was created from scratch and if it was resumed from background.

[image]

You can add a little hack if you want to know that your activity was started from another activity. Just put some extra in your intent like this:

In activity that will start new activity:

```
val intent = Intent(this, PSMainActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("CREATED_FROM_ANOTHER_ACTIVITY", true)
startActivity(intent)
```

In started activity:

```
 val intentt = getIntent()
 var wasCreatedFromAnotherActivity = 
     intentt.getBooleanExtra("CREATED_FROM_ANOTHER_ACTIVITY",false)
```